# Can't stop a Thread with a boolean flag

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm stuck with a following problem:

In c# form app I'm genereting Threads on a class function which should loop only if a boolean flag is set to false. But it won't break the loop upon changin the state of the boolean.

```
class Kasa {
    public bool _stop = false;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Kasa(int x, int y)
    {
        kasaImageNotActive = BufferedImage.getImage("kasa.jpg");
        kasaImageActive = BufferedImage.getImage("kasa.png");

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public void toggleAction() {
        _stop = !_stop;
    }

    public void act() {
        while (!_stop) {
             System.Console.WriteLine("aktiw " + x + " - >" + _stop);
         }  
    }
}
```

So in the Form code I'm invoking the "toggleAction()" function through a button click and it seems not to do the trick as the thread keeps on rolling and the whole application is not responding.

Comment: Try adding the `volatile` flag on your `_stop` field

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: Please post more complete code. The bug is not visible here.; Click the button and set a breakpoint in your loop. Inspect if _stop really turned true. Likely, it did not.

Comment: Adding volatile only didn't work. But when I added Thread.Sleep into act() function it did the work.

Comment: If the "whole application is not responding" then how could you have clicked the button?  A standard threading bug is calling Begin/Invoke() too often, causing the UI thread to burn 100% core and no longer responding to input.  And yes, a *bool* is not a thread synchronization object so the code is wrong as posted.  You can turn it into one with Volatile.Read() in the loop and Volatile.Write() in the event handler.

Comment: Another synchronization object that can be used is ManualResetEventSlim.
Call Set and Reset in ToggleAction() and Wait() in the loop in the act method...